# Divergence of Power Series on Boundary if there is a pole

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is an old qualifying exam problem:

Suppose $f$ is meromorphic (quotient of two holomorphic functions) on some open neighborhood on the closed unit disk. Suppose that $f$ has a convergent power series about 0 with radius at least 1. If $f$ has a pole at a point on the unit circle then show the power series diverges for each point on the unit circle.

I've successfully showed this for the case when the pole occurs at 1, but not for other values on the unit circle.

Comment: If one's handled the case of a pole at $z=1$, can't one rotate the general case in order to reduce it?